# How to get the output that I want?

Tags: tcl

Can someone point out what is wrong with my tcl script below ... I am new to tcl and try to figure out how to get the output that I want.

I want the "for loop" prints out the content of `descLvds1`, `descLvds2` ... `descLvds8` which is "LVDS1 loopback", "LVDS2 loopback" ... "LVDS8 loopback" but I can't get the output that I want ... here is part of the code, the problem is at the `$descLvds$i`, any help is appreciated ...

```
set descLvds1 "LVDS 1 loopback"
set descLvds2 "LVDS 2 loopback"
...
set descLvds8 "LVDS 8 loopback"

for {set i 1} {$i < 9 } {incr i} {
    puts "Chan$i $descLvds$i"
}
```

Comment: This is because when Tcl is parsing a piece of code, it only performs *one round* of variable substutition. Spend some time studying the [Tcl language rules](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) (there's only 12 of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set` both to set the value of a variable and get the value of a variable. To get the value of a variable that has a name which you compute from other variables, you can use variable substitution (eg: `$i`) to create the variable name and then use `set` to get the value of that variable.

Example:

```
for {set i 1} {$i < 9 } {incr i} {
    set varname "descLvds$i"
    puts "Chan$i [set $varname]"
}
```

You can combine those two lines into one if you want:

```
for {set i 1} {$i < 9 } {incr i} {
    puts "Chan$i [set descLvds$i]"
}
```

Comment: Bryan, it worked perfectly, thanks to your quick answer ...

Chan1 LVDS 1 loopback

Chan2 LVDS 2 loopback

Chan3 LVDS 3 loopback

Chan4 LVDS 4 loopback

Chan5 LVDS 5 loopback

Chan6 LVDS 6 loopback

Chan7 LVDS 7 loopback

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd name those variables slightly differently so you work with associative array elements. That would let you do this:

```
set descLvds(1) "LVDS 1 loopback"
set descLvds(2) "LVDS 2 loopback"
...
set descLvds(8) "LVDS 8 loopback"

for {set i 1} {$i < 9 } {incr i} {
    puts "Chan$i $descLvds($i)"
}
```

That *does* work.

Comment: So, you might want to consider accepting an answer then?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is due to manufacturing an abbreviated example for your question, but if the input elements follow the lexical order (`descLvds1`, `descLvds2`, ...), then you would be fine with appending to a list using `lappend` and a `foreach` loop:

```
lappend descLvds "LVDS 1 loopback"
lappend descLvds "LVDS 2 loopback"
# ...
lappend descLvds "LVDS 8 loopback"

foreach descLvd $descLvds {
    puts $descLvd
}
```